# calendar javascript call not working

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, content-security-policy

***EDIT***

I have tried the suggestions below and they still dont work. The error  I am getting is:

"Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-egiF+Vb0Vz6d/Eu2SO2D+0PSd3mbX/UWP8Bx7aqvuZQ='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback. "

Can anyone shed light on this meaning?

I am sure there is a simple answer and would very much appreciate it if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong. I am trying to call a basic calendar in an empty page. However nothing is happening. I have verified everything that I know to do but still nothing appears.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!--
        Customize this policy to fit your own app's needs. For more guidance, see:
            https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md#content-security-policy
        Some notes:
            * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
            * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
            * Disables use of inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
                * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
        -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" />
        <script src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js"></script>
            <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
    })

});
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="calendar"></div>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried running an F12 on the browser...see what the debugger info tells you?

Comment: check your browser's console for errors. That should be the first thing you do when "nothing happens"

Comment: Thank you. Here is the answer form the console:

Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-egiF+Vb0Vz6d/Eu2SO2D+0PSd3mbX/UWP8Bx7aqvuZQ='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is happening because inline scripts (i.e. scripts which are actually part of your page, and not loaded from a linked .js file) are disabled by your content-security policy. This is what the error message is telling you.

Assuming you want to allow them (despite the potential theoretical risk of XSS attacks), then the clue to enabling is in the comments right above it in your code:

> Disables use of inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
>
> - Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src

So simply modify the `default-src` section of the tag to include that directive. Change it from:

```
default-src 'self'
```

to

```
default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'
```

If you prefer not to do this, then the alternative is to move the Javascript from your page to a separate .js file and then provide a link to it using a `<script src=...` type of tag.

Note that none of this is in any way directly related to fullCalendar, and it is entirely about the security policy, which controls the scripts and resources a page is allowed to use. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP for an introduction to this topic.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining this. I am using this with Cordova to make an app. This is very very helpful for someone who is learning as he goes. Everyone else who sees this, please upvote because I cant.

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons that your code is not working. As information is insufficient so can't check the details. Here is working example of `Full Calendar`. Please follow it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // page is now ready, initialize the calendar..
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    weekends: false,
    dayClick: function() {
      alert('a day has been clicked!');
    },
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek'

  });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.3.2/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.3.2/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>


<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: thanks. What else would be helpful to see? This is the complete and only code on the page.

Comment: @brettm if this answer satisfy your need, please accept it and upvote